# Can I fill a google spreadsheet cell from a webservice Value?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping, gwt

In our company we use a google spreadsheet which contains the prices of all our products. This prices are available in USD & Euros.

Now, the problem is that everyday one guy has to look for the Euro exchange of the day, and then change it on a cell, so I was wondering if we could call a webservice to retrieve the currency exchange of the day and automatically update the cell without having a guy doing that, cause to be honest, is like Homer Simpson drinking bird, there is no sense doing that job,

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a case for a Google App Script https://developers.google.com/apps-script/

> Automate repetitive processes and workflows. Create scripts to automate expense approvals, time-sheet tracking, ticket management, order fulfillment, and much more.
>
> Link Google products with third party services. A script can send custom emails and a calendar invitation to a list from a MySQL database.
>
> Create custom spreadsheet functions. Apply customized formatting or do complex analysis on data in Google Spreadsheets.

There might be no use for GWT here.

Comment: We need to bill our customers in Canadian dollars for something which is priced in US dollars. We built a script in Google Apps Script. UrlFetch goes the the bank of Canada RSS feed, pulls out the noon rate and saves it into a spreadsheet. Another script, checks FreshBooks (our invoicing program) via API/UrlFetch for any items which need their prices updated and does the update.

Answer (score 1):

The `ImportXML` formula can query XML web services and process them with XPath. I think this is what you are looking for.

https://www.distilled.net/blog/distilled/guide-to-google-docs-importxml/